# Chaos Monkey:AWS EC2: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error on connecting to eu-central-1(frankfurt)

Tags: amazon-web-services, netflix, aws-sdk, simian

We are using Chaos monkey for resilience testing on AWS ec2 clients. When chaos monkey is trying to authenticate with the given secret key for frankfurt region, we are getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error.We are using AWS SDK for Java.

It is using signature version v2 and eu-central-1(frankfurt) requires v4. 
How can we set signature version to v4 or what setting we have to make to AWS SDK?

Here is the snapshot of the error:-

```
2015-01-19 05:37:05.028 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] Sending request -1804412292: POST https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1

2015-01-19 05:37:05.029 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] >> "Action=DescribeInstances&Signature=Ao5fLfM%2B/rOcbdll0LF0K2F9U8NBlgd%2BAwuFk83GOxo%3D&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-01-19T10%3A37%3A05.024Z&Version=2010-06-15&AWSAccessKeyId=xxx"

2015-01-19 05:37:05.029 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] >> POST https://ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1

2015-01-19 05:37:05.029 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] >> Host: ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

2015-01-19 05:37:05.030 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

2015-01-19 05:37:05.030 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] >> Content-Length: 225

2015-01-19 05:37:05.609 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] Receiving response -1804412292: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
2015-01-19 05:37:05.610 - DEBUG SLF4JLogger - [SLF4JLogger.java:61] << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the v4 signature [is explained here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html). The relevant bits for Java:

Add the following in your code.

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
```

Or, on the command line, specify the following.

```
-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4
```

Comment: i am using aws ec2 not s3. So the above solution is not working for me. I tried it as well.